Account Locks and Limits
I have a question regarding how account locks work on the runtime. We have a transaction that has 104 readonly accounts and 25 writeable accounts. This transaction is failing with TooManyAccountLocks.
I was under the assumption that the 128 account lock limit was only applied to writeable accounts. If this is applied to all accounts, does this mean the true limit to the number of accounts per transaction is 128? From the docs the limit is 256:

With the help of Address Lookup Tables, a transaction would now be able to raise that limit to 256 addresses per transaction.

In what case will the runtime not lock an account that's a part of a transaction?
